# Need to manage the column height and pass variables as widget property

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

This my code for a card widget. This will go in as a child of a ListView.builder widget

```
class CardHome extends StatefulWidget {
  String cardHead;
  String cardDesc;
  String cardTime;
  String cardDate;

  CardHome(
      {this.cardHead, this.cardDesc, this.cardTime, this.cardDate});

  @override
  _CardHomeState createState() => _CardHomeState();
}

class _CardHomeState extends State<CardHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 6,
          globals.blockSizeVertical * 3, globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 6, 0),
      width: globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 87,
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.circular(SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 4.5)),
        color: Color(globals.secColor),
        elevation: 0,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: globals.blockSizeVertical * 2.7,
              horizontal: globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 6.5),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 56,
                    child: Text(
                      'Buy Plane Tickets',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          height: globals.blockSizeVertical * 0.14,
                          fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 3.5,
                          letterSpacing: globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 0.1,
                          color: Color(0xff171b20)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '8:20',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Arboria',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 3.8,
                        color: globals.inactHeadTextColor),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: globals.blockSizeVertical * 2,
              ),
              Container(
                width: globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 70,
                child: Text(
                  'Buy Tickets for departure on 14th May, 2020 at 2:15pm',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 3,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 3.5,
                      letterSpacing: globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 0.02,
                      color: Color(0xff171b20)),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: globals.blockSizeVertical * 2),
              Text(
                '23 January',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Arboria',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: globals.blockSizeHorizontal * 3.3,
                    color: globals.inactHeadTextColor),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How it looks:
[image]

My Problem is the Column occupies the full available height as you can see in the image (dark part).
I even tried using `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` but it did not work. Any way I can fix the height so it looks like a proper card?

Also as I said I need to pass this widget to a ListView.builder so cardHead, **cardDesc, cardTime, cardDate variables need to go in place of the Strings which I had manually typed (eg. Buy Plane Tickets, 23 January, etc) while passing the widget**. For example the cardHead works as a property which I can use in the listview builder like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: headers.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return CardHome(
      cardHead: Text('${headers.[index]}'),
      cardDesc: Text('${descriptions.[index]}'),
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've had a similar problem with my own projects, (albeit with Rows which set the width to infinity) and the only satisfactory conclusion I've come to is this.

The "Column" widget automatically overrides any and all constraints for height to infinity.  So you need to manually set the constraints of each of the child widgets inside the Column.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 50,
      child: [Your First Child Widget in the Column Here],
    )
    Container(
      height: 10,
      child: [Your Second Child Widget in the Column Here],
    ),
  ]
),
```

It's not always perfect, but it does work.  Also if you need to have something in there that automatically resizes, you can alway wrap them in an Expanded Widget instead.

Hopefully that helps!  (Note: you'll need to do the same kind of thing with Rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add height property to the container

```
class _CardHomeState extends State<CardHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100 // for example 100
```